# changing values of struct tm in function

Tags: c, struct

I'm working on a function which should prompt the user to enter an arbitrary time and date.
These values I want to store in struct tm, but it doesn't work properly:

```
struct tm * enter_time_GMT(){
    struct tm *TIME;
    char input[50];
    int check=0, buffer;

    printf("date:\n");
    do{
        printf("day > ");
        scanf("%49s",&input[0]);
        buffer=atoi(input);
        if(buffer>=1 && buffer<=31){
            check=1;

            /* program crashes here, compiler says TIME uninitialized: */
            TIME->tm_mday=buffer;
        }
        else{
            check=0;
            printf("wrong input\n");
        }
    }while(check==0);
    /* just a short part of the full function */
    return TIME;
}
```

I'm using the function like this:

```
int main(){
    struct tm *sysTIME; /* why does the compiler want me to use tm* instead of tm? */
    char buffer[80];

    sysTIME=enter_time_GMT();
    strftime(buffer, 80, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", sysTIME);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

To my surprise I may use things like

```
TIME->tm_year=12;
```

work in main(), but not in my function. So where is the difference, and what is the difference between struct tm and other structs?

Comment: You are returning a pointer to the local variable TIME which goes out of scope as soon as you leave the function.

Comment: Does anyone have a hint how to avoid this? I'm stuck at the moment. The alternatives I tested so far all failed.

Comment: `struct tm *TIME;` -> `struct tm *TIME = malloc (sizeof struct tm);`. In your program you dont initialize the TIME pointer hence the crash.

Comment: Thanks alot! This works fine, exactly as I want!

Comment: @Jabberwocky I needed parentheses around struct tm: malloc (sizeof (struct tm));

Answer (score 0):

When your compiler says that `TIME` isn't initialised, it is correct. Your pointer `TIME` doesn't point anywhere meaningful and accessing it will likely crash the program.

From your comments I see that you are not yet familiar with pointers. In that case, you can use a `struct tm` directly. That way you don't have to worry about memory management, because `struct`s are passed by value.

If you want to use pointers, you must make the pointer either point to valid memory. One way to get that is to allocate memory on the heap with `malloc` or `calloc`. That memory will then be accessible from outside your function, but you should `free` it later, when you don't longer need it.

The example program below uses both methods: `xmas` works with pointers and `newyear` works with a plain `struct tm`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct tm *xmas(int year) 
{
    struct tm *t = calloc(1, sizeof(*t));  // must be free'd after use

    t->tm_mday = 24;
    t->tm_mon = 11;
    t->tm_year = year - 1900;

    return t;  // pointers to memory on the heap can be safely returned
}

struct tm newyear(int year) 
{
    struct tm t = {0};

    t.tm_mday = 1;
    t.tm_mon = 0;
    t.tm_year = year - 1900;

    return t;  // structure is returned "by value"
}    

int main()
{
    struct tm *x = xmas(2014);
    struct tm ny = newyear(2015);
    char buf[30];

    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%D", x);
    puts(buf);

    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%D", &ny);
    puts(buf);

    // Free ressources of allocated memory
    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Using plain structures is probably easier until you have a firm grasp of pointers (which includes more than allocation of memory on the heap).